# Facing issue in windows SDK headers are not recursively included in Visual Studio Managed C++ project

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, managed-c++

I have created a simple Managed C++ project where I access CPoint from Atltypes.h. When compiling I am getting error 'errno.h' header not found. But I checked the project -> Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories... The header path is included.

The file errno.h is available in SDK path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt'

But while compiling it is not able to pick it up. Is it due to any environment issue in my pc? Or is my visual studio settings corrupted?

[image: Code]

Answer (score 0):

After some more googling found that windows.h is key header which has all types. After adding below 2 headers in managed C++, it works fine

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <msclr/marshal.h>
```